# How to add zoom effect to bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a zoom effect to a bootstrap carousel but I just can't seem to get it to trigger :(

I believe that I may have to add the syntax to the core _carousel.scss file (or possibly not?).  So with this in mind, I have tried adding to the regular CSS file and also to the _carousel.scss file but with no joy.

Can any fellow coders out there help, please?

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-image-1 {
  background: url("../img/image1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-2 {
  background: url("../img/image2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-3 {
  background: url("../img/image3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
 from {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
 }
 to {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
 }
}

@keyframes zoom {
 from {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
 }
 to {
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
 }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  -webkit-animation: zoom 5s;
  animation: zoom 5s;
}

<section id="showcase">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1 active"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-2"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you want to trigger?

Comment: would like it to trigger on each slide so that all slides have the zoom animation applied

Comment: How about this? https://codepen.io/altafhpatel/pen/JWGxBq

Comment: Managed to find a different solution with applying the key frames in a different manner but your approach would of also been a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and is ok

```css
.carousel-inner .carousel-item > img {
  -webkit-animation: thing 20s;
  -o-animation: thing 20s;
  animation: thing 20s; 
}
@keyframes thing {
  from {
     transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clip-path: circle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).